# Styling Facebook Likebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

Is there a way to style the facebook likebox without a plugin? I have my likebox on a darkish background and the blue link that says my facebook pages name is not blending well, I would like to change all the text colors inside the likebox, do I have to do this with javascript?

Comment: If it can be done with a plugin- it can be done without it...

Comment: I tried to use css but its in an iframe. I'm asking how to do it without a plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not to change the style of the facebook plugins for two reasons:

1. It's what the users are used to, it's what they search for if they want to like the page, that blue like button/box.
   If you change it users might just miss it.
2. Facebook change things, quite frequently, if you hack their style you'll need to constantly keep track of their changes so that the box still looks good.

Comment: Well if they can't read the text, then they won't notice it either. This facebook likebox is lying on a grayish background so the blue is really meshing with it so u can't read it. So I disagree with your point but appreciate your opinion.

Comment: Well, it will be much easier to place the plugin in a container with a different background color or play with its' opacity. I don't know your design and if it will fit in, but styling your own dom is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 implementation and then style using css. Pure css would be better than the iframe method, where you would have to inject css into the iframe. It would be better though to write your own javascript code that way you can control the entire box and not just text colors. If you need help with any of this, just post where your at, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

this should solve your problem:- http://fitzhughweb.com/2011/06/how-to-style-a-facebook-like-box-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

Is it not in the TnC's of Facebook not to change the colours of the boxes.  I'm sure it says somewhere you must use it on a white background if the case is similar to yours?